# Testing area for pull requests and my own work

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I develop on a VM, and when I commit, I currently let my IDE (PHPStorm) "deploy" to a staging area on my VPS for further testing in the production environment before I manually do the real deployment to the live area (simple `rsync -a /var/www/myproject/staging/public/* /var/www/myproject/public`). Currently the staging area doesn't have a git repo, because no development is done there.

But now, while I'm slowly picking away at development of a feature branch in my limited spare time, a friend has started to help me by fixing bugs on the `master` branch, creating pull requests on Github. For simplicity, I'd like to use the same staging area to test her code before merging it and deploying it live. I'm a git novice, so this might be a dumb question, but how do I get the code of the Github master branch plus a pull request to the staging directory?

If I need to have a repo there so that I can follow steps like [this](https://dev.to/bolajiayodeji/how-to-test-a-pull-request-locally-before-merging-1h29), I don't mind. But since my IDE appears to just copy code files, not the repo I commit to on my VM, I don't want anything to get confused or out of sync over time. Or perhaps I should stop deploying from my IDE altogether and always just get code (for testing either my code or my friend's code) straight from Github - I don't know. What's the "right" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

as per me you should take the following approach

1. Ask her to checkout a new branch with the fixname(Incase she has already coded and commited in master in her local do the following to seperate the branch):

```
make sure your are in master branch if not created a seperate branch already
git checkout -b fix/fixname   --please specify the name for fix relevantly
git push origin fix/fixname
```

2. ask your teammate to create a PR by pushing her code her branch into fix/fixname and PR should be against master from fix/fixname branch.
3. handle any review comments which you would like to be addressed.
4. in staging place a copy of branch fix/fixname.

once the code is tested, merge the PR fix/fixname into master(ensure to rebase with master before merging the PR finally).

Comment: Steps 1-3 are already done. It's step #4 I'm asking how to do.

Comment: in the staging area, you will need a git repo, and then checkout branch fix/fixname there and then deploy the same code in staging environment.

Although we do not code in staging, its crucial to deploy in staging via git branch nly as it reduces any errors being introduced.

you will need to do git init in the staging deployment envt and link your bug fix branch there ..

Comment: I don't know what commands accomplish what you're saying. At the moment I decided that I want to see her changed files run with what I already have (including the current work on my feature branch - she worked on different files, so there is no conflict), but I can't even figure out how to view or download the two files she changed! No matter what I click on Github related to the PR, all I see are diffs, not files.

Comment: I finally figured out that I could go the branch associated with the PR (branches tab, not PR tab) and download the ZIP, and then FTP the two files that changed. But there's got to be an easier way.

Comment: for automatic deployments, you can configure jenkins

Comment: I've never heard of that, but I don't need to automate it - how do I even do it once?